# Timer1 stops firing

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, timers

I am trying to use interrupts to play notes on a speaker.  Timer2 works fine, but after about 15 seconds, Timer1 stops firing for about 5 seconds, and then it comes back on.  If I keep running the sketch, it will stop and resume every now and then.

Here is my code:

```
#define SPEAKER1 8
#define SPEAKER2 7
volatile bool swap1;
volatile bool swap2;

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
    digitalWrite(SPEAKER1, swap1);
    swap1 = !swap1;
}

ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect)
{
    digitalWrite(SPEAKER2, swap2);
    swap2 = !swap2;
}

void playNote1(unsigned note) { //Play a note on Timer1.
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
    cli();
    bitSet(TCCR1B, CS10);
    bitSet(TCCR1B, CS12);
    unsigned ticks = (16000000 / 1024) / (note);
    ticks /= 2;
    OCR1A = (ticks <= 65535 ? ticks : 65535);
    SREG = oldSREG;
}

void playNote2(unsigned note) { //Play a note on Timer2.
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
    cli();
    bitSet(TCCR2B, CS20);
    bitSet(TCCR2B, CS21);
    bitSet(TCCR2B, CS22);
    unsigned ticks = (16000000 / 1024) / (note);
    ticks /= 2;
    OCR2A = (ticks <= 255 ? ticks : 255);
    SREG = oldSREG;
}

void stopNote1() {  //Stop playing a note on Timer1.
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
    cli();
    bitClear(TCCR1B, CS10);
    bitClear(TCCR1B, CS12);
    SREG = oldSREG;
}

void stopNote2() {  //Stop playing a note on Timer2.
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
    cli();
    bitClear(TCCR2B, CS20);
    bitClear(TCCR2B, CS21);
    bitClear(TCCR2B, CS22);
    SREG = oldSREG;
}


void setup() {
    pinMode(SPEAKER1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(SPEAKER2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    // initialize timers
    cli();          // disable global interrupts
    TCCR1A = 0;     // set entire TCCR1A register to 0
    TCCR1B = 0;     // same for TCCR1B
    // turn on CTC mode:
    bitSet(TCCR1B, WGM12);
    bitSet(TIMSK1, OCIE1A);

    TCCR2A = 0;     // set entire TCCR2A register to 0
    TCCR2B = 0;     // same for TCCR2B
    // turn on CTC mode:
    bitSet(TCCR2A, WGM21);
    bitSet(TIMSK2, OCIE2A);
    sei();          // enable global interrupts
}

void loop() {
    playNote1(523);
    delay(1000);
    stopNote1();
    delay(500);
    playNote1(131);
    delay(2000);
    stopNote1();
    delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using those ISRs instead of PWM?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that answers what I asked...

Comment: You're twiddling pins manually instead of letting the hardware do it.

Comment: Fair enough. But the hardware timers can do square waves too. Try COMnx[1:0]=0b01, WGM1[3:0]=0b0100, and WGM2[2:0]=0b010.

Comment: They represent all the sequential bit places that should be accessed. The datasheet uses this convention quite a bit.

Comment: It means WGM22, WGM21, and WGM20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that **you never reset Timer1 counter (`TCNT1`) when you stop a note and then play another one**.

Also, changing the clock divider selection to "*no clock*" by clearing bits **CS10** and **CS12** as you do is not the most effective way to stop the timer; in fact, rather than stopping it, you can let it run but just **disable its interrupts**.

I have modified your program and this worked correctly:

```
#define SPEAKER1 8
volatile bool swap1;

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
    digitalWrite(SPEAKER1, swap1);
    swap1 = !swap1;
}

void playNote1(unsigned note) { //Play a note on Timer1.
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
    cli();
    unsigned ticks = (16000000 / 1024) / (note);
    ticks /= 2;
    OCR1A = (ticks <= 65535 ? ticks : 65535);
    TCNT1 = 0;
    bitSet(TIMSK1, OCIE1A);
    SREG = oldSREG;
}

void stopNote1() {  //Stop playing a note on Timer1.
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
    cli();
    bitClear(TIMSK1, OCIE1A);
    SREG = oldSREG;
}

void setup() {
    pinMode(SPEAKER1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    // initialize timers
    cli();          // disable global interrupts
    TCCR1A = 0;     // set entire TCCR1A register to 0
    TCCR1B = 0;     // same for TCCR1B
    TCCR1C = 0;     // same for TCCR1C
    // Set clock divider
    bitSet(TCCR1B, CS10);
    bitSet(TCCR1B, CS12);
    // turn on CTC mode:
    bitSet(TCCR1B, WGM12);
    bitClear(TIMSK1, OCIE1A);
    sei();          // enable global interrupts
}

void loop() {
    playNote1(523);
    delay(1000);
    stopNote1();
    delay(500);
    playNote1(131);
    delay(2000);
    stopNote1();
    delay(500);
}
```

Note that I have removed all code for Timer2 as it does not play any role in the initial problem.

The important changes are:

1. `setup()` now performs Timer1 setup completely (CTC mode, clock divider); note that I also included **TCCR1C** to ensure full setup (it is preferrable as Arduino libraries may have initialized it differently before `setup()` is called); it also ensures Timer1 interrupts are initially disabled.
2. `playNote1` now clears `TCNT1` **and then** enable Timer1 interrupt for `TIMER1_COMPA_vect`
3. `stopNote1()` just disables Timer1 interrupt for `TIMER1_COMPA_vect`

To be complete, you would also want to limit **useless consumption** on output **pin 8**, thus stopping a note should also force its output level to `LOW` (or `HIGH` depending on your actual circuit behind, but `LOW` is more likely):

```
void stopNote1() {  //Stop playing a note on Timer1.
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
    cli();
    bitClear(TIMSK1, OCIE1A);
    swap1 = false;
    SREG = oldSREG;
    digitalWrite(SPEAKER1, LOW);
}
```

#### Now what about your code for Timer2, the code is the same, so why does it work?

Actually it doesn't :-)

But you can't hear the difference between Timer2 is an 8-bit counter so if you don't reset it, then it won't take long until it reaches 255 and resets to 0, so only the first wave phase will be wrong but your hear won't notice that...

So **you should also modify the code for Timer2** to make it correct.

Comment: Wow!  I never would have guessed that!